# How to automate grunt tasks on file changes in asp.net core

Tags: gruntjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Grunt to minify the less,css and js through task runner explorer. Is there a simple way to automate these tasks. I want grunt to create & minify css files when my less file are changed. And minify javascript files when any of js files are modified.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Visual Studio extension [Bundler & Minifier](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40) which does exactly what you want.

When you install the extension, you can right click the file you want to minify and select "Minify file". Then on your Task Runner Explorer right click the "All Files" option and add a binding to Before build